# Database Driver Distribution

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

Even though I developed many utility software dealing with several database platforms, I still don't know much about the basics of database connectivity.

I am developing a WPF application at the moment. My aim is to give the ability to the end user to connect to any database (especially the etnerprise level large scale platforms such as Oracle, DB2, SQL Server and also the popular ones such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQlite etc.) even if the user is not installed the relevant driver on his system.

I don't know how to proceed. Should I distribute all the drivers with my application? Is there a one-size-fits-all solution? Can I distribute an Oracle driver, without having user to install Oracle client in his system for example? I wonder what is the best way to do this. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Which "database drivers" are you wondering about? They're probably distributed with .NET.

Comment: I updated the question. Especially the etnerprise level large scale platforms such as Oracle, DB2, SQL Server and also the popular ones such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQlite etc

Comment: Most of that is distributed with .NET. What makes you think it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ADO.NET for database connectivity

- You should program against the DbXXX set of classes (DbConnection,DbCommand etc) to remain database agnostic
- You should use the standard [provider factory mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories.getfactoryclasses%28v=vs.90%29) to obtain a list of installed providers and generate required DbXXX instances.

You cannot connect to a database without installing it's corresponding driver! You need not distribute the drivers; that is something each user of your application can do depending on which database he wants to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that could potentially be solved with an elaborate installer process. You could bundle up the install packages for the database drivers you wish to distribute with your application into your app's MSI file and include a custom install routine that allows the user to choose which database engine he would like to interface with. Armed with that information your installer could then execute the appropriate driver installation routines..